How to prove the following conclusion about minimal ideals?
Problem: Let $A$ be a minimal left ideal of the associative algebra $R$. Then either $A^2 = 0$, or $A=Re$, where $e$ is an idempotent.
Since $A$ is a minimal ideal, either $A^2=A$ or $A^2=0$. When $A^2\neq 0$ and $A^2 = A$, there exists a non-zero element $a\in A$ such that $a=bc$, where $b, c\in A$. Thus, $A=Ab =Rb$, but I am unable to prove the existence of the case where $b$ is an idempotent.

@Thusle Gadelankz, oh yeah, I checked it out, and it's indeed the same principle. Thank you very much.
